# Recording voice clips in Alexa Custom Skill

Tags: alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

Is there any way to record/stream audio clips from Alexa to send them to a backend service?

For example, how do I build a skill which records voice memos and sends them to a backend service to be stored, and read later?

Cannot currently find any way to record clips and store/stream them to a backend service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this feature is available to developers yet. Amazon has mulled over it in the past but because of security and privacy issues, it still has not made it a feature.